# How to convert csv text to numbers as well as manipulate almost non-machine readable data in Power Bi?

Tags: excel, csv, pivot, powerbi

I have a sales datasheet that is in csv, that I input into Power BI. The monetary values on the sheet come up as decimal placed numbers (e.g 123.0000) but Power BI reads it as text. When I try and convert this to a fixed decimal number ($) it kicks back an error. How do I convert this safely to ($)? There are also multiple columns with these values in them. How would I convert all of them in the easiest way, as there are other columns with just normal numbers between these monetary columns? (1 x SOH column and then 1 x Net column - this repeats)

On top of this, the datasheet is spread in such a way that is is difficult to manipulate the data into a form that is easy for Power BI to read. The header rows begin with the SKU code and description, but then move over to each individual store (retail store) by location as well as being broken up into SOH and Net, per store per column. I've been racking my brain on this for ages and can't seem to find a simple way around it. Any tips would be great.

For the conversion to ($), I went into the csv sheet, altered the format of the numbers and saved it as a .xml, but the issue with this is that I would have to repeat this tedious step every time I would need to pull data, which is a lot.

For the layout of the original spreadsheet, I tried unpivoting the data in Power BI, which does work. However, it is still sectioned off by Net and SOH, which means I have to add a slicer in just to see Net or SOH on its own, instead of having them as separate entries.

I expect the output to firstly give me fixed decimal numbers, but all I get is an error when trying to convert the numbers to $.

With the unpivoting, I can manipulate the data by store, which is great and helps, but I have to create a separate sheet which has the store ID's on it so that I can"filter" them when I want to switch between them (again, a slicer is necessary). I expect to be able to look at the store individually as well as overall and then also look at the Net individually and SOH individually, by store and as a whole. From there I can input my cost sheet and calculate the GP.

I have attached a picture of the data. I can drop a sample sheet somewhere as well if necessary. I just need to know where.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All you have to do is change the regional settings, not on your laptop specifically but rather within Power BI itself.

Go to File > options and settings > options > regional settings > change to English (United Kingdom) {thats the region that worked for me and fixed everything automatically}